# How to create multiple PDFs with different content from a single data frame?

Tags: r, latex, knitr

## Problem

I want to knit multiple PDFs from a single data frame. Therefore I've tried various solutions, but my knowledge in R, R Studio, LaTex, knitr is very limited so I wasn't able to adapt some solution approaches and finally tried it on my own. I actually think my code is absolutely not the way you actually use to achieve what I want to achieve. So, please feel free to tell me where and what I can/should improve.

I would be really grateful for some help. I've been googling for hours now and I would also appreciate if you could recommend me any tutorial/guide/explanation. I don't even know where to start.

## Current State: Solved

## Code

#### main.R

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  g_title <- rownames(mtcars)[i]
  knit2pdf(input  = "main.Rnw", 
           output = paste0("output\\", g_title, ".pdf"), 
           quiet  = FALSE, 
           envir  = parent.frame())
}
```

#### template.Rnw

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  Titlepage
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{Topic 1}
\newpage

\section{Topic 2}    

\end{document}
```

## Solution Approaches

#### Global Variables

I tried to create global variables which are altered by a for loop. These variables are then used in the .Rnw file in form of a function. I wasn't able to get this working due unknown errors.

Code in the .R file:

```
printPlot <- function() {
  print(g_plot)
}

for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  g_title <- rownames(mtcars)[i]
  g_plot  <- ggplot(mtcars[i,], aes(x = cyl, y = disp) ) + 
             geom_point()
  knit2pdf(input  = "main.Rnw", 
           output = paste0("output\\", g_title, ".pdf"), 
           quiet  = FALSE, 
           envir  = parent.frame())
}
```

Code in the .Rnw file:

```
<<>>=
printPlot()
@
```

Errors:

The PDFs are created, but their contents are messed up. You can see it in the image under 'Current State'.

I also receive several error/warning messages, e.g.:

> Warning messages:
>       1: running command '"C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe"
>   --quiet --pdf "Mazda RX4.pdf" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1 
>       2: running command '"C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Programs\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe"
>   --quiet --pdf "Mazda RX4 Wag.pdf" --max-iterations=20 -I "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1

#### MakeFile

I just read the first time about makefile. Maybe this could help solving the problem.

If I got it right makefile is used with Markdown and not directly with LaTex. This seems to be a massive loss in performance. This point is quite important to me, so I will try to find another solution.

#### Other SO Questions

In most of the cases I tried to adapt the code, but simply failed, because I am missing knowledge to understand the given solution approaches.

- [R Knitr PDF: Is there a posssibility to automatically save PDF reports (generated from .Rmd) through a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30422008/r-knitr-pdf-is-there-a-posssibility-to-automatically-save-pdf-reports-generate?rq=1)
- [Using loops with knitr to produce multiple pdf reports… need a little help to get me over the hump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396755/using-loops-with-knitr-to-produce-multiple-pdf-reports-need-a-little-help-to)
- [Can Sweave produce many pdfs automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8519128/can-sweave-produce-many-pdfs-automatically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, I'm not entirely sure about the expected output, but there concept is clear. And although the task itself is quite simple, surprisingly many things can go wrong.

Code:

**`code.R`**

```
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)

dir.create(path = "output/")
opts_knit$set(base.dir = "output/")

for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars)) {
  filename <- rownames(mtcars)[i]
  knit(input  = "template.Rnw", output = paste0("output/", filename, ".tex"))
  tools::texi2pdf(paste0("output/", filename, ".tex"), clean = TRUE)
  file.copy(from = paste0(filename, ".pdf"), to = paste0("output/", filename, ".pdf"))
  # file.remove(paste0(filename, ".pdf")) # this will DELETE filename.pdf from the current working directory (should be safe because we just created this file)
}
```

**`template.Rnw`**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
ggplot(mtcars[i,], aes(x = cyl, y = disp) ) + geom_point()
@
\end{document}
```

- We need to set [`base.dir`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#package-options) because the current working directory is one level above the directory where the document is created. This would lead to wrong figure paths: knitr produces the plots in `figure/` but they should be in `output/figure/`. Consequently, compilation will fail.
- For some reason `knit2pdf` cannot compile the generated intermediate TEX file. Therefore I use `knit` to produce a TEX file and then `tools::texi2pdf` to compile this file to PDF.

Note how variables from `code.R` are visible to the code in the template document. That's why `i` can be used in `template.Rnw`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It's just working fine and it's even pretty straight forward. You mentioned that the file name MUST not contain whitespaces. From other languages I know it's 'only' highly recommended. Did I missed something there?

You did a really good job here. Thank you again!

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, I was wrong about the whitespace; it's not a problem and I edited the answer accordingly. While I was preparing the answer, I opened one of the TEX files in RStudio and wanted to click "Compile PDF". Then RStudio claimed that filenames *must* not contain whitespaces. But apparently this does not apply with `tools::texi2pdf`.

Comment: Thank you once again for your effort!