# knit2pdf formatting incorrectly, producing warnings

Tags: r, knitr

I have been using knitr for a while to generate some quite complex PDFs.  On one of my machines knit2pdf started to cause me issues, and I cannot figure out why.  knit2pdf continues to work on my other machines.

My typical setup is:

**test.Rnw**

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\end{document}
```

**R Command**

```
knit2pdf(input = "latex/test.Rnw", output = 'latex/knit2pdf', clean = TRUE)
```

however, I receive the following error message:

> knit2pdf(input = "latex/test2.Rnw", output = 'latex/knit2pdf', clean = TRUE)
>
> processing file: latex/test2.Rnw
>   |.................................................................|
>   100%   ordinary text without R code
>
> output file: latex/knit2pdf
>
> [1] "latex/knit2pdf.pdf" Warning message: running command
>   '"C:\PROGRA~1\MIKTEX~1.9\miktex\bin\x64\texify.exe" --quiet --pdf
>   "knit2pdf" --max-iterations=20 -I
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/tex/latex" -I
>   "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/share/texmf/bibtex/bst"' had status 1

and the contents of knit2pdf.pdf is:

> article[]graphicx[]color fgcolorrgb0.345, 0.345, 0.345
>   [1][rgb]0.686,0.059,0.5691[1][rgb]0.192,0.494,0.81[1][rgb]0.678,0.584,0.6861[1][rgb]0,0,01[1][rgb]0.345,0.345,0.3451[1][rgb]0.1framed
>   kframetotalleftmargin@ setminipage @end@of@kframe shadecolorrgb.97,
>   .97, .97 messagecolorrgb0, 0, 0 warningcolorrgb1, 0, 1 errorcolorrgb1,
>   0, 0 knitrout alltt upquote.styupquote document This is a test

I have managed to get the output I require (using the example from [How to create multiple PDFs with different content from a single data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43350590/how-to-create-multiple-pdfs-with-different-content-from-a-single-data-frame)), but with significantly more work than just calling knit2pdf.

```
filename <- "texi2pdf"
f_tex <- paste0("latex/", filename, ".tex")
f_pdf <- paste0("latex/", filename, ".pdf")

knit("latex/test.Rnw", output = f_tex)
tools::texi2pdf(file = f_tex, clean = TRUE, quiet = FALSE)
file.rename(from = paste0(filename, ".pdf"), to = f_pdf)
```

And in this case the PDF output (texi2pdf.pdf) is simply, and correctly,

> This is a test

I am running R 3.3.2 and all packages are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

The solution as outlined by Yihui Xie [on Github](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1394#issuecomment-295073346) is to append the output file with '.tex'

i.e.

```
knit2pdf(input = "latex/test.Rnw", output = 'latex/knit2pdf.tex', clean = TRUE)
```

I was running knitr v1.11 which did not require this, but later versions do.